# Audio Editing Podcatcher

Tags: windows, linux, download-manager, podcast, audio-editing

I need a Podcast Manager that automatically downloads podcasts in the background to my MP3 player. I also want it to divide those podcasts into 5 minute segments, and increase the volume.

I'm on Windows 8.1 and Linux. I prefer gratis software but would be willing to pay up to £10. I would accept a script that connects more then one softwares that do the work collectively.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Does the software need to be gratis or would you be wiling to pay for it (how much if so?). Would multiple tools that can be chained be fine for your case? (Like a download manager that fetches the podcasts, an audio editor that makes chunks and volume and a script that connects them and drops the files where your MP3 player will find them)

Comment: So long as it's collectively automagic I don't mind. Thank you kindly.

Comment: How about price?

Comment: Preferably free but I might run to say £10.